# Conflict Task WebPart and Discussion Board WebPart

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-addin, csom, client-side-rendering

There is an issue when adding "Tasks WebPart" and "Discussion Board WebPart" in the Same Page, checking and unchecking "Tasks Async Feature" breaks like shown here :

[image]

There is no error in the console, i don't get it, what's going on ?

Background :

- Team Site (MDS Enabled)
- I Used the Wiki Page and WebPart Page.
- Content added to both Apps

You can reproduce the issue by adding the two WebParts in any page you want.